# client connect() succeeds before the server accept(), how does the client know that server accept() is successful?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, tcp

If client connect() succeeds before the server accept(), how does the client know that server accept() is successful?
What happens if send() is called during the time gap between connect() succeeds and server accept(), will there be an error?

Answer (score 1):

> If client connect() succeeds before the server accept(), how does the client know that server accept() is successful?

By sending a request and succeeding in getting a response.

> What happens if send() is called during the time gap between connect() succeeds and server accept(), will there be an error?

No. The data will go into the socket receive buffer at the server.

Comment: 'ending a request' - what kind of request? Can you elaborate? Do u mean calling a 'connect' again and get a response back? Thanks.

Comment: EJP mistyped & meant sending not ending.